# CDI Injection Abstract and Generics

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm looking for a solution or an explanation of my scenario.

I have an Abstract class which has a field that I want to be injected.

```
public abstract class AbstractBean<T extends IModelBean> implements IBean<T> {


    @Inject
    private IDAO<T> dao;

    @Override
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return dao.selectAll();
    }
}
```

One of the concrete implementations would be this ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScope
public class PersonBean extends AbstractBean<Person> {}
```

So I expect CDI to inject this IDAO implementation.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PersonDAO extends AbstractDAO<Person> implements Serializable {

    @Override
    public List<Person> selectAll(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm calling from this Facelet page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>JSF and CDI with abstract class</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:dataTable value="#{peopleBean.all}" var="person">
        <h:column >
            <h:outputText value="#{person.name}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column >
            <h:outputText value="#{person.position}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:body>
</html>
```

It does compile, but when Weld tries to inject the `dao`object, GlassFish gives me the following message.

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IDAO<IModelBean>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private br.personal.mateusduboli.cdi.abstract_class.beans.implementation.AbstractBean.abstractDAO]
at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:82)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:68)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1039)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:283)
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:189)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:203)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
```

I managed to get it working by placing the field on the child class, but it does not solve my problem.

I want to know if there is any solution or explanation of why it doesn't work.

Thanks.

EDIT: Added the concrete implementation and the facelet page which is calling the method.
EDIT2: Added the IDAO concrete implementation.

Comment: Could you please post the the injection point and the concrete classes that extend from `AbstractBean` as well? Spec section 4.2 does show an example of this, but there are several other conditions and would be useful to see the injection point and the concrete implementations. See http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/.

Comment: Well, the first problem I see is that your concrete implementation is annotated with `@ManagedBean`. Make sure that when you're working with CDI you only use CDI and EJB annotations. Mixing these with JSF annotations such as `@ManagedBean` won't work. Try `@Named` and make sure that `@RequestScoped` is from `javax.enterprise.context.*` package.

Comment: Do `AbstractDAO` implement `IDAO` and `AbstractBean` implement `IModelBean`?